# From when did C start using variable length arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Please tell me why the following code runs even on a `strict C-99 compiler`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    a[1]=10;
    a[2]=5;
    printf("%d %d",a[1],a[2]);
}
```

The variable declaration must occur before any other statements in C right? If we so want a dynamically allocated array, we have to use memory allocation functions like `malloc()` but how come it is taking and input integer and allocating that sized array?

Comment: Both [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and intermingled declarations/code were added in C99.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and is supported by the C99 standard.
This does not work in C89 or any version of C++.

Comment: this is working on normal C compiler too, but i thought the original C standard doesn't allow it

Comment: C99 also adds the ability to mix declarations and statements within a block. C++ has always had this; C90 did not.

Comment: @sasidhar: Define "normal C compiler", please. Most C compilers don't fully support *any* language standard by default; you typically have to add additional command-line arguments. For gcc, `-ansi -pedantic` causes it to conform quite closely to C89/C90; for (almost) C99 conformance, use `-std=c99 -pedantic`.

Comment: Right! C89/C90 requires all variable declarations to be at the beginning of a block. This is very definitely only valid C99 code.

Comment: @Prashant: Or it could be taking advantage of a compiler-specific extension; gcc supports mixed declarations and statements even when not in C99 mode.

Comment: @Prashant So keeping aside weather it is recommended or not, i can allocate my array anywhere in the code like `C++ or java` for C too?

Comment: Keep the scope of this question focused to C. This code won't work at all on C++.

Comment: I am just asking is it `like` C++ or java now in C (after the introduction of this new rule)

Comment: If "it" means using non-constant expressions to allocate variable-length arrays, then no. If "it" means intermixing declarations and statements, then yes.

Comment: Works for me in C++ http://cpp.sh/43oh6  Did something change?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there are two mechanisms in this code snippet that are not allowed in C90, but are in C99. The first is the variable size array declaration, using `a[n]`. The second is the mixing of declaration and code, with `a` being declared after a line of code.

I find [this list by David Tribble](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C90-mixed-decl-stmt) handy. It is focused around C++ but gives you a good overview about the differences between C90 and C99 as well.

> If we so want a dynamically allocated array, we have to use memory
>   allocation functions like malloc()

Apparently you already know, but worth mentioning anyway: `malloc()` is used to allocate memory on the heap. The array in your example is allocated on the stack, which is a different mechanism. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80113/1380680) for an excellent explanation of the differences.

Comment: agreed, i am not more concerned about where the allocation is done. My question is weather the C Standard allows it?

Comment: C99 does. See [here](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C90-mixed-decl-stmt) for more information about C99 and C90 -- I know that page is mostly about C++ but has good information about C as well, with exact references where to look in the language specifications.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is called [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and to answer your question specifically, they were introduced in the C99 standard (probably some C compilers had them before, but any C99-compliant compiler *must* have them).

You'll find plenty of SO answers recommending you don't use them. With `malloc()`, there is a defined interface for memory allocation to fail: the call returns `NULL`. With VLA, there is no such interface: it's undefined behavior what happens when an allocation fails.

Answer (score 1):

C99 allows for variable length arrays as in your example.

[here](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444) is an artcile about it explaining more